# Удаление в списке

Tags: c

Делаю двусвязный список. сделал для него удаление, но проблема в том, что если элемент один, то программа падает, а вот если удалить первый, последний элемент или промежуточный, то все нормально? Подскажите, что нет так.

```
APTEKA* DeleteElem(APTEKA* pdel)
{
    if(pdel == head)
    {
        head=head->next;
        head->prev=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return head;
    }
    if(pdel == tail)
    {
        tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return NULL;
    } else
    {
        APTEKA *pnext;

        pdel->next->prev=pdel->next;
        pnext=pdel->prev->next=pdel->next;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return pnext;
    }
}
void FreeElemMemo(APTEKA* pel)
{
    free(pel->inf.name);
    free(pel->inf.group);
    free(pel->inf.form);
    free(pel->inf.day1);
    free(pel->inf.month1);
    free(pel->inf.year1);
    free(pel->inf.day2);
    free(pel->inf.month2);
    free(pel->inf.year2);
    free(pel->inf.price);
    free(pel);

}
void Deleting(void)
{
    int key = 0;

    APTEKA* pel=head;
    char name_del[20];
    puts("Введите название препарата");
    scanf("\n%s", name_del);

    while(pel!=NULL){
        if(!stricmp(name_del,pel->inf.name)){
            pel=DeleteElem(pel);
            key = 1;
        }
        else {
            pel=pel->next;
        }
    }

    if(key == 0)
    {
        puts("Такого препарата нет");
    }else if (key == 1)
    {
        puts("Препарат успешно удален");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("\n%s", name_del);` - что здесь делает это `\n`?

Comment: это если название совпало, то должно удалить данный элемент

Comment: Еще раз: что делает это `\n` в строке формата `scanf`?

Comment: чтобы ввод в name_del происходил с новой строки

Comment: или это вопрос с подвохом?

Comment: Никакого "ввода с новой строки" это не даст. С чего вы взяли, что добавив туда `\n` вы получите "ввод с новой строки"? `\n` перед `%s` в `scanf` вообще ничего не дает - оно не имеет никакого эффекта. Это бессмыслица.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут собака зарыта

```
head=head->next;
head->prev=NULL;
```

Получается что вы делаете `head = NULL`, а затем `NULL->prev = NULL`. А затем ещё пытаетесь очищать поля у уже присвоенного `NULL`

Comment: if(pdel == head && pdel == tail)
    {
        head->next=NULL;
        head->prev=NULL;
        tail->next=NULL;
        tail->prev=NULL;
        FreeElemMemo(pdel);
        return NULL;
    }

Comment: Попытался добавить иф, если элемент и хвост и голова, теперь не вылетает, но не удаляет элемент